# How to trigger index controller from plugin in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I try to use plugin to dispatch bootstraps for different modules. However, for some reason, I can not trigger controller for each module, and the error is "EXCEPTION_NO_CONTROLLER". Any one could give some advice about it?

```
// Plugin Code:
class Plugin_AccessCheck extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {
    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
        if ('admin' == $request->getModuleName()) {
            require_once APPLICATION_PATH .'/modules/admin/Bootstrap.php';
            $moduleBootstrap = new Admin_Bootstrap();
            $moduleBootstrap->bootstrap();
        } else if('site' == $request->getModuleName()) {

        }
    }
}

// Module Bootstrap:
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap{    
    public function Admin_Bootstrap() {
    }

    protected function _initAutoload() {
        define("localhost", "adrian");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think ZF1 works the way you think it does.

Answer (score 2):

All module bootstraps are run on *every request*.

If there is some processing you wish to perform when the request is routed to single module, then register a plugin - either in application bootstrap or in module bootstrap; as noted above, they will all run - that exits early if the request is not targeted at his module.

See this post by MWOP for further discussion:

http://www.mwop.net/blog/234-Module-Bootstraps-in-Zend-Framework-Dos-and-Donts.html

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure..if i unserstand your question..you can try

```
public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{
   $request = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();
    if ('admin' == $request->getModuleName()) {

        require_once APPLICATION_PATH.'/modules/admin/Bootstrap.php';

        $moduleBootstrap = new Admin_Bootstrap();

        $moduleBootstrap->bootstrap();

    }
    else if('site' == $request->getModuleName()){
               $request->setModuleName('othermodule');
                $request->setControllerName('othercontroller');
                $request->setActionName('otherindex');
    }
}
```